# Get values from two tables using a look-up table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, lookup

I would like to show all actors in movies that came out in a specific year (say 1980) and sort them by actor name.
Thanks.

```
actors_table:<br />
id<br />
name<br /><br />

movies_table:<br />
id<br />
name<br />
year<br /><br />

cast_table: (look-up table)<br />
actor_id<br />
movie_id<br /><br />
```

The result would look like:

```
actor name     movie name        movie year<br />
Bill Bob       Movie One         1980<br />
Dave Smith     Movie Two         1980<br />
Jane Jones     Another Movie     1980<br />
```

Comment: Learn to use JOINS https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple INNER Join on Lookup table with actoe and movie table.

```
SELECT AT.name actorname, MT.name moviename, MT.year movieyear
FROM actors_table AT 
     INNER JOIN cast_table CT ON AT.ID = CT.actor_id
     INNER JOIN movies_table MT ON MT.ID = CT.movie_id
```

[Working Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d6ada/2)

Comment: Thanks. Just needed to add: where MT.year = 1980